# How to embed machine learning python codes in hardware platform like raspberry pi?

Tags: python, machine-learning, raspberry-pi, artificial-intelligence, robotics

I want to implement machine learning on hardware platform s which can learning by itself Is there any way to by which machine learning on hardware works seamlessly?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Helpful may be ["how to ask good questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python supports wide range of platforms, including `arm-based`.

You raspberry pi supports Linux distros, just install Python and go on.

Comment: I mean raspberry with python .I already know python basic and advance but want raspberry with python source.

Answer (score 0):

First, you may want to be clear on hardware - there is wide range of hardware with various capabilities. For example raspberry by is considered a powerful hardware. EspEye and Arduio Nano 33 BLE considered low end platforms.

It also depends which ML solution you are deploying. I think the most widely deployed method is neural network. Generally, the work flow is to train the model on a PC or on Cloud using lots of data. It is done on PC due to large amount of resources needed to run back prop. The inference is much lighter which can be done on the edge devices.